# Cannot use seas() function from seasonal package in R

Tags: r, time-series, seasonal-adjustment

I am trying to make seasonal adjustment for a data in R with `seasonal` package.

While using it with my own data I get

`Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection In addition: Warning message: In file(con, "r") : cannot open file '/var/folders/lz/y98s6mjd0wj20yg753975_gm0000gn/T//RtmpmbiMm1/x132069375fe11b/iofile.est': No such file or directory`

[image: error]

Example of my data, which is a monthly, electricity usage data.

```
structure(list(TP_ELEKTUKETIM_TKT1 = c(829993.67, 828500.35, 
794785.03, 780987.81, 794123.54, 801793.81, 920212.91, 887967.7, 
837716.33, 765780.2, 791234.38, 836844.05, 862093.97, 855170.09, 
793270.11, 671752.87, 670617.73, 789836.94, 920637.78, 923602.56, 
907935.74, 805712, 837915.2, 865274.32, 861818.14, 860445.29, 
886330.82, 853433.59, 804124.56, 885961.42)), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

But while using `unemp` dataset from the package or a reproduced seasonal data I do not get this error and I can get the result.

```
> set.seed(111)
> toy <- abs(sin(seq(1, 60, by = 1) * 2 * pi / 12) + rnorm(60))
> toyts <- ts(toy,frequency = 12,start = 2010,end = 2015)
> seas(toyts)

Call:
seas(x = toyts)

Coefficients:
         Constant  AR-Nonseasonal-01  
          -0.2602             0.1147
```

or

```
> seas(seasonal::unemp)

Call:
seas(x = seasonal::unemp)

Coefficients:
AR-Nonseasonal-01  MA-Nonseasonal-01     MA-Seasonal-12  
           0.9436             0.8254             0.8507
```

I tried to update all packages, re-downloaded `seasonal` and `x13binary` packages but I don't understand why it works with sample datasets but not with my own. I also tried to unlist and turned my data into double datatype and still did not work. Thanks for replies.

Comment: This isn't all of it, but X-13 needs 3 years of data and you have 30 months = 2.5 years. When you make your `ts` object with 4 years specified, it copies the data to extend it to 49 months from jan 19 to jan 23, but everything past month 30 is misaligned.

Comment: It runs without error if I make my `ts` extend to 2025, so I think this is an issue of an uninformative error for a too-short data sample. (but note, this was done by repeating your 30 months of data, so the 2nd half of it is misaligned.)

Comment: Yep, I think that may be the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I did not clearly specify the ts() so that seas() could not work properly. I needed to revise my ts() and data so that it didn't have any re-used or missing time series data.